# New Tag Proposal: Self-Referential

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There's a lot of questions that result in code that refers to itself. Typically these questions get assigned the [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) tag, though it's not quite applicable in some cases.

I propose a new tag [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential), which is applied to questions where the answers in someway refer to their characteristics, such as length or characters. While there's some overlap with [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine), I believe this can be reconciled by having [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) refer to challenges that have to output or generates versions of themselves, such as [permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161990/quine-of-orders), [sections](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44915/print-out-the-first-n-characters-of-your-code), or [backwards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/print-your-code-backwards-reverse-quine).

Some questions that would benefit from adding the [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential) tag (and maybe removing the [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) tag):

- [Output your score!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160646/output-your-score)
- [Output with the same length as the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121056/76162)

  - [Create output twice the length of the code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59436/76162) and other variants
- [Print every character your program doesn't have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12368/76162)
- [What is the smallest positive base 10 integer that can be printed by a program shorter (in characters) than itself?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67921/76162)

Something like the [self-identifying quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/76162) or [print every character you program doesn't have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12368/76162) might get both tags.

Comment: So self-referential programs doesn't need to fully know all information about itself, while quine does.

Comment: For example "a program that calculates its sha-256 hash" is self-referential (... or it is not?)

Comment: And... no, I think self-identifying quine should be a quine. It's possible to calculate its own source code by running it over all strings until something matches.

Comment: @user202729 In the question I suggested `quine` refer to code that outputs its source code transformed in some way. It makes more sense to call a self-identifying program "self-referential" than "quine-like", though the fact that programs would usually have to generate the source code to compare against is why I suggested it gets both tags. A "sha-256" program would probably be closer to a quine because while the hash is semi-unique for each text, it's not an intrinsic attribute of a program.

Comment: @user202729 Not necessarily. You might end up with a collision instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential) would be strictly weaker than [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine). [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine) should only be used for tasks involving the actual manipulation of the program's source, which is not required for the challenges linked.

While "Output with the same length as the code" could *theoretically* be done by using a standard extensible quine to get the source, computing the length of the source and using that to generate a string, it is unlikely that would be competitive. Because it is not the only viable approach to solving the challenge, [self-referential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-referential) is more appropriate.

This distinction seems useful to make.